# reload spring bean during the runtime

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I am trying to change bean property value during the runtime.

WebConfig

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService service;

    @Bean
    public SecurityPolicy securityPolicy() {
        SecurityPolicy policy = new SecurityPolicy();

        //takes data from db, it works fine
        policy.setMaxAttempt = service.getMaxAttempts();
        return policy;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class SecurityPolicyController {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityPolicy policy;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/security")
    public ModelAndView update() {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView(); 

        //set data to db, it works fine aswell
        service.setMaxAttempts(7);

        //now i am trying to reload my beans
        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).refresh();

        //something reloading but i still get the same value
        System.out.println(policy.getMaxLoginAttempts());
        model.setViewName("security"); 
        return model;

    }
}
```

Changing the value occurs only when the server is rebooted.
Can you suggest example how to achieve bean reloading during the runtime or tell what I'm doing wrong? All help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not inject the `service` into `policy`? and everytime you call the `policy.getMaxLoginAttempts()` the call gets delegated to `service.getMaxAttempts()`. So you get new values returned, without having to reload.

So the config looks like this:

```
@Bean
public SecurityPolicy securityPolicy() {
    return new SecurityPolicy(service);
}
```

And the `SecurityPolicy.getMaxLoginAttempts()` like this:

```
public int getMaxLoginAttempts(){
    return service.getMaxAttempts();
}
```

Comment: SecurityPolicy bean injecting into different service, and in this service this way i still have old values

Comment: where does service get its values from? A static source?

Comment: from SecurityPolicy bean

Comment: no i mean the other service, the one that provides `maxAttempts` to policy

Comment: the SecurityService  takes maxAttempts from database

Comment: basicly i implement Authentication Attempts with Spring Security from this http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-block-brute-force-authentication-attempts , and now i am trying dynamicly change maxAttempts

Comment: I think you didn't understand the concept completely. Because in your example, you're only accessing the value once (that's why you have to reload). But when on every call the new data get's collected thats much simpler and also much better design (like what I did)